# What happen if an exit occur inside the atexit handler?

Tags: c

I know that atexit is used to register a function handler. Then when an exit in the code occur that function is called. But what if an exit occur inside the function handler?

I was expecting an infinite loop but in reality the program exit normally. Why?

```
void handler(){
    printf("exit\n");
    exit(1);
}

int maint(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    atexit(handler);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger. Debug it and you will see how it is implemented in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior is undefined.

> **7.22.4.4 The exit function**
>
> [2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4p2) The exit function causes normal program termination to occur. No
>   functions registered by the at_quick_exit function are called. If a
>   program calls the exit function more than once, or calls the
>   quick_exit function in addition to the exit function, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Calling `exit` in an `at_exit` handler (that is being run during the normal processing of exit) is definitely a second call to exit.

Exiting normally is a possible behavior, but seeing as anything can happen (the nature of the behavior being undefined), it could very well result in catastrophe. Best not to do it.

Comment: (Calling `exit` in an `at_exit` handler is definitely a second call to `exit` if the handler was called due to `exit` being called, but a handler may be called by the program normally, in which case it would be the first `exit` call. But then it would be called again, unless the handler took a different code path.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok, but why it doesn't create an infinite loop? The behavior is undefined, so it can create loop or, as in this case, not create it?

Comment: Undefined means undefined. It could do anything, and it is meaningless to ask _of the standard_ why a particular thing did or did not happen. You can only ask why your implementation did a particular thing, and the answer is almost always "because it did".

Answer (score 1):

As you have been pointed to, the behaviour is undefined.... but despite of that, trying to justify your observed behaviour, the library writers normally tend to cope with strange programmer behaviours (like the *at least strange* of calling `exit()` while the program is in `exit()`)  I'll say:

- It is possible that the `exit(3)` function, before calling any of the exit handlers, just unregisters it from the list of signal handlers.  This would make the `exit(2)` function to call each exit handler **only once** and not to call the handler recursively.  Just try to register it again to see what happens would be a good exercise.
- It is possible that the exit function, marks itself as being run and if called inside a  handler, just return, as if nothing happens.
- It is possible your expected behaviour that could lead to a stak overflow (no pun here :))
- It is possible to ...

Whatever happens is part of the U.B. commented in other answers, but for a library that tries to extend on the standard and behave normally, the probably best behaviour is to avoid recursive calls in exit handlers in some of the ways proposed.

On the other side, you had better not to use this *feature* (let's call so) in your programs, because, as it is not endorsed by the standard, can lead you to trouble if you port your programs elsewhere in the future.

You probably think on `exit(3)` as a function that is never to be called twice (apart from recursively, like you expose) but think you have several threads on your program and two of them call the `exit(3)` function at the same time.

The probable best behaviour is to have some kind of semaphore that allows the handlers to be protected from mutual access... but the best way to have the list of handlers for short time compromised, is to unlink one handler from the list (let's consider the list a queue, where each thread comes and takes a handler)  they get the handler, unlock the queue and then execute it.  This can lead in each handler being executed by one thread of the ones that have called `exit()`.  The first thing an implementor faces it how to deal with several threads calling `exit()` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> POSIX.1 says that the result of calling exit(3) more than once (i.e., calling exit(3) within a function registered using atexit()) **is undefined**. **On some systems (but not Linux), this can result in an infinite recursion; portable programs should not invoke exit(3) inside a function registered using atexit().**

[found here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-atexit/)